# How to create a level 3 menu item via db in a custom joomla component?

Tags: joomla, menu

I am working on a Joomla 3.4 component that allows creating articles of a certain category from the front-end. The creation of the article is working as intended. Now, I want to add a menu entry for that article. Everything is working for that, except the values for the **rgt** and **lft**.

The menu entry is intended to be level 3. The parent's ID is set in the back-end configuration. Is there a Joomla expert who could give me a short explanation of how the lft and rgt values of the menu entry itself and probably its parent and the parent's parent would have to be set?

Comment: Why no  just use the menu API to create the menu item? In no way should you try to mess with your own rgt and lft, it's very complex because it uses JTableNested and you need to update the entire tree.  Did you know that the core com_content article create menu item lets you specify that article create defaults to a certain category? You could just make it so users can't change the category rather than make a whole new component.

Comment: Thank you for the hint about the menu API, I did not encounter it in the documentation before. The article is not only created from the user entry, but also a "footer" containing additional information and linking is created. The component is about creating articles about teachers and their lessons respective, the component is linking teachers and articles to each another and giving a contact form. For each teacher and lesson, a menu entry is generatetd That's why I am building a component instead of using the "create article" menu item.

Comment: Sounds like a plugin .. but anyway look in com_menus. It's convluted because it's really old code, but basically I would create a MenusTableMenu instance and add the item with the appropriate parent value set, then after save do rebuild() --- unless that is happening already, I really did not go look at the code in depth, but that should send you in the right direction.

Comment: rebuild() sounds fine, thanks. Manually I can make it work by opening the menu entry in the backend and saving it, lft and rgt are then recalculated and it works.

Comment: Solved: `$menutable = JTable::getInstance('menu', 'JTable');
   if(!$menutable->rebuild())
   {
    JError::raiseError('500', 'Rebuild failed');
   }`

Comment: You should post this as an answer and then accept it.